# Visual Studio 2022 can connect to localdb but SSMS 18.10 can't

Tags: visual-studio, ssms, localdb, sql-server-2019

Spanking brand-new installations of:

- Visual Studio 2022 Community (VS)
- SQL Server 2019 Dev (SQL)
- SQL Server Management Studio v18.10 (SSMS)

There are no other Visual Studio or SQL Server instances or installations.

A console program creates a localdb database using Entity Framework successfully. VS SQL Server Object Explorer documents this with a connection to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` using a connection string of:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;
    Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
    TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;
    MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

But I can't get SSMS to connect to this `localdb` database instance.

I am trying to use this server name:

```
(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

What am I doing wrong? I get an immediate (2 second) response with:

> The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I used sqllocaldb, and everything looks ok:

```
sqllocaldb info
MSSQLLocalDB
ProjectModels

sqllocaldb info MSSQLLocalDB
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            15.0.4153.1
Shared name:
Owner:              GreenMachine\jean
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    1/21/2022 11:38:11 AM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#878B8E4E\tsql\query
```

So I tried another tack. I pointed my EF connection string to the local SQL Server instance:

```
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data source = GreenMachine; Initial 
 Catalog=SamuraiAppData; Integrated Security=True; 
 TrustServerCertificate=True;")
```

And that worked - I got a new database created on that instance. It seems like SSMS can't connect to localdb!

Thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

From the SSMS connection dialog, click the Options button in the lower right corner to expand the connection options.  Ensure that Encrypt Connection is *not* checked.

[image]

Comment: A good idea, but no, the "Encrypt connection" is not checked. "Trust server certificate" is checked, but other than that, my screen has the same options for "Connection Properties."

Comment: @DavidRogers - Well, darn.  Would you care to post screenshots of the rest of the settings panels in the connection dialog?

Comment: Nothing is entered/checked in "Always Encrypted" and "Additional Connection Parameters".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after completing an MVC/Entity tutorial and I managed to connect using SQLSMS v19.1 by doing the following.

I used the same 'Server name' as David above:

[image]

In Visual Studio, the 'SQL Server Object Explorer' had a 'Connection string' property of:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False
```

I accepted all the defaults in SQLSMS but added these to the 'Additional Connection Parameters' tab:

[image]